# Tax on Canadian investments for a Canadian expat in UK

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, canada, capital-gains-tax

I have never studied accounting before looking for some guidance on my issue. I have investments in Canada that I have to file tax returns for capital gains and dividend income. However my primary residence is in London, UK working full-time with T2 General visa. Could you direct me to some online resources I can read to learn how to file taxes myself in my situation?